# how to highlight a specific area in book's image?

Tags: android

i want to achieve the same result as in the link below.
it is a page image from an" islamic book ",when you long clicked on one area it will  somehow get highlighted.
http://android.quran.com/images/scr_3.png

Answer (score 0):

Android has the default behaviour to highlight text in a textview when you long press on it. Make sure in your view's properties in the layout.xml file, you add the following:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

in some cases you might even need to add the following attributes as well:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:longClickable="true" />
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply it is helpful but i think i didn't give a good explanation,that book's page is actually an imageview ,so how it is possible to highlight it?

Comment: @Didine Sorry I wouldn't know how to help you then. Not sure that what you're asking is easily achievable. It sounds as you might need some kind of OCR reader, or maybe know the coordinates of the text beforehand and create active zones on your screen using Canvas. Let us know if you manage to do it in the end! Good luck!

Comment: Thank your for your support ,as i know the developer used a database for the texts, i will let you know if i find          any solution.